# About potentials with infinitely many bound states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Let's say I have two quantum systems. The first is described by the Hamiltonian $H_{1}=-\Delta+V_{1}$ and the second by $H_{2}=-\Delta+V_{2}$. If $H_{1}$ has an infinite number of bound states and $V_{2}<V_{1}$ does this imply that also $H_{2}$ has an infinite number of bound states.
Moreover I am interested in general criteria to determine whether a Schrodinger operator has infinite eigenvalues or not in 3D.
 Edit: assume both potentials being negative almost everywhere

Comment: Regarding the first part. Hint: What happens when you compare harmonic oscillator with a free particle problem?

Comment: Ok right. I will edit the question because in fact I am thinking about negative buond states and negative potentials. Maybe that changes something.